# Sufficient conditions for $G\cong N\times G/N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Given a normal subgroup $N$ of a group $G$, do there exist sufficient conditions that allow us to conclude that we have an isomorphism
$$ G\cong N\times G/N?$$

Comment: To summarize: you need a map $p : G \to N$ that restricts to the identity on $N$.